# Cloudinary missing cloud_name in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, cloudinary

I am using the cloudinary with my application to upload images but I seem to get this error on development. I have the site launched and it gives this error when I try to upload an image.

`Uncaught Missing required option: cloud_name`

When I run it in development (localhost), it doesn't throw this error and works perfectly. Is this an issue in my production.rb or development.rb files? Did I forget to include something?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually because I never pushed my keys to heroku with figaro. I'm using a Backbone.js frontend and a rails backend and I ignore my cloudname and API keys in gitignore so it was never on heroku.

I had to run: 
`figaro heroku:set -e production`
and then it all worked :)